# Javascript +ES: Is there any difference between [...arr] and arr?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider a scenario where in you are trying to iterate over a const array.
Would there be any difference between

```
[...arr].forEach((elem) => {
  // your operations
});
```

and

```
 arr.forEach((elem) => {
   // your operations
 });
```

Can these two be used interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, they can. I don't see why you would want to use the first expression rather than the second one.

Comment: Yes!! a constant array will only have the address as constant, you can still change/add elements to it. But when you use the spread operator, you don't touch the original array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It will make a copy of the array. If the callback function would use the `array` parameter and it would modify it, that would make a difference. E.g.:

   ```
   [...arr].forEach((val, i, a) => a.push(val))
   ```
2. If `arr` is not an array but an *array-like*, it will turn it into an array and thereby allow you to `forEach` over it. E.g.:

   ```
   [...document.getElementsByTagName('p')].forEach(p => console.log(p))
   ```